# How to check if user with a specific ID exists?

Tags: sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-apps

I have to loop through all Rows in a table that contain a user field. I have to retrieve those users and do nasty stuff with them:

```
private void GetUsrInfo(FieldUserValue user, ClientContext clientContext) {
    int id=user.LookupId;

    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    User spuser = web.GetUserById(id);
    clientContext.Load(spuser);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Mail = spuser.Email;
}
```

This works. However these are "old" entries and a lot of these persons do not even exist anymore. The user-field still contains the data of that now abandoned user, but when I try to retrieve the userdata by `GetUserById()` I retrieve the following exception:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: User cannot be found.
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()

Currently I just catch these Exceptions and proceed to the next user. 
But this is bad and very slow.
Is there a more smart way? Anything like *"if web.UserExists(id)..."*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

One possible way to check whether or not the user exists, without throwing an error or creating a new user (as result of the `web.EnsureUser(@"domain\username")` method) is to load the complete collection of users locally and use a LINQ statement to lookup the user by Id.

For example:

```
UserCollection collUser = ctx.Web.SiteUsers;
ctx.Load(collUser);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var user = collUser.Cast<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1);
if (null != user)
{           
    Console.WriteLine("User: {0} Login name: {1} Email: {2}",
            user.Title, user.LoginName, user.Email);
}
```

If there is a record where the ID == 1, it will be returned, if not the return value will be null.

Depending on the number of users in the site, this may have performance concerns, however, based on the number of exceptions you expect to generate checking the user ID, this solution may be feasible.

Reference: [Csom or rest to verify user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/130708)

Comment: I only have an Id. In addition "EnsureUser" does more that just searching for a user. It also adds the user to the site. In short: Does not help in my case

Comment: Did you check the second answer in the question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/130719/75930, This may be closer to your use case in which you are not adding the user to the site

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. The second might work using the Id. Still have to check how the performance is. If you paste the code here I am happy to upvote your answer (Cannot do this until it is changed)

Comment: Updated the answer, Unfortunately I am not able to help test the performance of loading the user collection locally, however, I would be curious to know the number of users you will check against and how this performs.